# Solving heat equation by Duhamel's theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The general solution for heat equation

$$u_t = - \frac{1}{\alpha} u_{xx}$$

with Duhamel's theorem yields to

$$u(x,t) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{4\alpha t}} \int_{\tau=0}^t \frac{f(\tau)}{(t-\tau)^{3/2}}\exp\Big( \frac{x^2}{4 \alpha (t-\tau)}\Big) d\tau$$

How can I go further by applying the actual boundary condition of

$$f(t) = k e^{-t}$$

*I assumed that the steps of solution to a famous PDE is known and I avoided, but if it is needed, I can post the whole solution.*

Comment: You should simply put the initial condition in the integral and than solving it, doesn't seem like a pretty integral

Comment: Are you sure that the solution if of that type?